# How to calculate $P ( X = 1 | X + Y \geq 0)$

Tags: probability

Hi I am currently studying for my exam and are to calculate $P ( X = 1 | X + Y \geq 0)$ where Y does not depend on X and

$$
P_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
0.2 \ \ \ ,x=-1 \\
0.3 \ \ \ ,x=0 \\
0.5 \ \ \ ,x=1 \\
0 \ \ \ \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
P_Y(y) = 
\begin{cases}
0.3 \ \ \ ,y=-1 \\
0.4 \ \ \ ,y=0 \\
0.3 \ \ \ ,y=1 \\
0 \ \ \ \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
I know that by conditional probability we have
$$
P ( X = 1 | X + Y \geq 0)  = \frac{P(X=1 \cap X+Y \geq 0)}{P(X+Y \geq 0)}
$$
which I have tried to calculate by calculating all of the above options, which are a lot, but I know the answer is $50/77$ which I do not get. How do I calcucate the above? I know that I can't use the fact that X and Y are independent as they depend in this particularly case.

Comment: "which I have tried to calculate by calculating all of the above options, which are a lot" -- I think this is relevant work. Can you include it? Or at least summarize it?

Comment: "I know I can't use the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent" -- but your very first sentence claims they are independent?

Comment: Oh I can see that I have typed it incorrectly as Y is independ of X but not the other way around. My calculations are:

Comment: Note that independence is a two-way street; $Y$ is independent of $X$ if and only if $X$ is independent of $Y$. You will need to use independence as an essential part of your solution.

Comment: $P(X=1 | X+Y \geq 0) = \frac{P(X=1) \cdot P(Y=-1) + P(X=1) \cdot P(Y=0) + P(X=1) \cdot P(Y=1)}{P(X=-1) \cdot P(Y=1) + P(X=0) \cdot P(Y=0) + P(X=0) \cdot P(Y=1) + P(X=1) \cdot P(Y=0)}$

Answer (score 1):

Working from your comment that said:

> $P(X=1 | X+Y \geq 0) = \frac{P(X=1) \cdot P(Y=-1) + P(X=1) \cdot P(Y=0) + P(X=1) \cdot P(Y=1)}{P(X=-1) \cdot P(Y=1) + P(X=0) \cdot P(Y=0) + P(X=0) \cdot P(Y=1) + P(X=1) \cdot P(Y=0)}$

Your numerator looks good, but your denominator is missing a few cases -- specifically, the cases $\{X = 1, Y = 1\}$ and $\{X = 1, Y = -1\}$.

Comment: Thanks I see that I missed a few. Is there any easier way to calculate this?

Comment: I don't think there is *generally* a much easier way to go about this than carefully enumerating the cases. For this *specific* problem, you can take a small shortcut; note that if $X = 1$, then $X + Y \geq 0$ automatically; hence, your entire numerator could just reduce to $0.5$, and the two terms you missed, along with $\{X = 1, Y = 0\}$, could all combine together for a total probability of $0.5$ as well.

Comment: Thanks Aaron! :)

Comment: However, Aaron, you said Y is independent of X if and only if X is independent of Y. But if this was the case, in this particular problem, the answer would be $1/2$ as $P(X = 1 | X+Y \geq 0) = \frac{P(X=1 \cap X+Y \geq 0)}{P(X+Y \geq 0)} = \frac{P(X=1) \cdot P(X+Y \geq 0)}{P(X+Y \geq 0)} = P(X=1)$ which is not the case?

Comment: $Y$ is independent of $X$, which you used repeatedly in your calculations. But, $X$ is not independent of the variable $X + Y$.

Comment: Oh ok, makes sense. Thanks!